# AS3 hitTest logic regarding instances of two different classes

Tags: class, object, actionscript-3

I have instances of Class A and Class B and need help with the hitTest logic between the two on them.
When I drag an instance of Class B on stage I want any instances of Class A which will come on stage by AS3 will be automatically called by object instances of Class B for hitTestObject with A. I cannot create array (predefined & code compression) point.

I have already did this in past but forgot syntax arrangement.. but I am pretty clear how it was done.

Created class A
created method to let target this.

Created class B
import A
call method from A to find object
do hitTestObject

please help me out in the flow

Need this in ActionScript 3.0;

Comment: Or you can just add the **hitTest** logic into your parent class instead. Since it controls the adding of class A and class B objects, it should also check if they collide. PS: I did not downvote but you cannot request free code. Show your own problematic code and we'll help you to fix it

Comment: I edited your question to make a bit more sense but I had trouble with some of the part regarding the hitTest logic. Please try to edit your question a bit more especially where you are explaning the hitTest logic. Add real code and then you might get more help.